# How to automatically run an emulator in terminal

Tags: react-native, android-emulator

- In Desktop

  (The emulator turns on automatically)

[npm start video](https://youtu.be/uUhNKguiao4)

[terminal(?) image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k913N.png)

[emulator image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GY4MG.png)

- On the laptop After turning on the emulator can activate the React-Native

  Which program is the terminal image among the images?

  (Powershell X, Azure X, cmd X, ...)

I want to use it like a desktop

- case of me

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.

> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!